# Java Spring Boot Entites not saving to JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

That's my first project with Spring Boot implemented. I tried going step by step with official Spring tutorial but I'm stuck with a problem that I can't find any answer about.

Whenever I try to call findAll() or find() method on my repository it returns empty array [].

Even with manual preloading enitites like done in tutorial and immediately trying to display database content I get the same result.

I can guess I'm missing something silly, but I can't figure it out for some hours now. What's the cause? Tomcat/jpa/spring version mismatch? Missing annotation somewhere?

Here's my `AnimalRepository.java`

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<Animal, Long> {
}
```

`LoadDatabase.java`

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Configuration
class LoadDatabase {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadDatabase.class);

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(AnimalRepository repository) {

        return args -> {
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Lion("Bilbo")));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Lion("Frodo")));
            log.info(repository.findAll().toString()); //try to log content to console
        };
    }
}
```

The logging above basically ends up with this console output:

[logging result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhQPG.png)

Probably not as important, but `AnimalController.java`

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class AnimalController {
    private final AnimalRepository repository;

    AnimalController(AnimalRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    @GetMapping("/animals")
    List<Animal> all() {
        repository.save(new Lion("Bilbo")); //this doesn't work either
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    @PostMapping("/animals")
    Animal newAnimal(@RequestBody Animal newAnimal) {
        return repository.save(newAnimal);
    }

    @GetMapping("/animals/{id}")
    Animal one(@PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new AnimalNotFoundException(id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/animals/{id}")
    Animal replaceAnimal(@RequestBody Animal newAnimal, @PathVariable Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
                .map(animal -> {
                    animal.setName(newAnimal.getName());
                    animal.setSpecies(newAnimal.getSpecies());
                    return repository.save(animal);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newAnimal.setId(id);
                    return repository.save(newAnimal);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/animals/{id}")
    void deleteAnimal(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

And the finally `Lion.java`

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Lion implements Animal {
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String name;
    private String species;
    private int requiredFood;
    //private Zone zone;

    public Lion(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.species = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        this.requiredFood = LION_REQUIRED_FOOD;
    }

    public Lion() {

    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpecies() {
        return species;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSpecies(String species) {
        this.species = species;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRequiredFood() {
        return requiredFood;
    }

    @Override
    public void setRequiredFood(int requiredFood) {
        this.requiredFood = requiredFood;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Animal animal))
            return false;
        return Objects.equals(this.id, animal.getId()) && Objects.equals(this.name, animal.getName())
                && Objects.equals(this.species, animal.getSpecies());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.id, this.name, this.species);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal{" + "id=" + this.id + ", name='" + this.name + '\'' + ", species='" + this.species + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

I tried switching JpaRepository to CrudRepository, but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that your data haven't been saved to the database, because of the transaction. try to change your `repository.save()` to `repository.saveAndFlush()`

Comment: Tried that, but no luck. However I went straight ahead to using abstract classes instead of interfaces and that started working. I guess interfaces aren't supported to be an Entity